# How to build this structure in HTML with Bootrstap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGzeWb)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-push-8 col-md-4 menu-top">
      <ul>
        <li>text 1</li>
        <li>text 2</li>
        <li>text 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">    //this structure need to be below (not inline)
      11231231
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      11231231
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      11231231
    </div>
  </div>  
</header>
```

I put an image to understand better what I want to do

http://i64.tinypic.com/3342ofa.png

How to build HTML structure so as to be like in the picture above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO users are not here to program your website for you. Figure it out for yourself, **_then_** if you're having trouble, come back.

Answer (score 0):

Use **thumbnail** for image which is a class of Bootstrap.

**Example :**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a href="example.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    <p>Stack Overflow</p>
    <img src="stack.jpg" alt="Stack Overflow" style="width:150px;height:150px">
  </a>
</div>
```